# Service can't start or connect to pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio, services, kodi, xinit

I installed Ubuntu Server 23.04 and afterwards manually installed `kodi` and `pulseaudio`.
I'm also using the `kodi-standalone` service to start kodi automatically on boot.

The problem is, that the service does not start or use pulseaudio, but if I start it via ssh (`sudo -iu kodi, then pulseaudio --start or -D`) and then manually kodi (`kodi --standalone`) it works.

The service looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kodi standalone (X11)
After=remote-fs.target systemd-user-sessions.service network-online.target nss-lookup.target sound.target bluetooth.target polkit.service upower.service mysqld.service lircd.service
Wants=network-online.target polkit.service upower.service
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
User=kodi
Group=kodi
#EnvironmentFile=-/etc/conf.d/kodi-standalone
PAMName=login
TTYPath=/dev/tty1
ExecStart=kodi --standalone
# OR
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xinit /usr/bin/kodi-standalone -- :0 -quiet -nolisten tcp vt1
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall --user kodi --exact --wait kodi.bin
Restart=on-abort
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
Alias=display-manager.service
```

And pactl info if I log in via ssh and sudo to the kodi user:

```
Server String: /var/run/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 14
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: pulse
Host Name: dockerbox.local
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 16.1
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-surround
Default Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-surround.monitor
```

I read that the file `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/pulseaudio` should start pulseaudio but I'm missing the file and the folder.
If I add `puleaudio -D` or `start-pulseaudio-x11` to `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` it also does not work.

Comment: the "solution" was to remove kodi incl. the service and install jellyfin